# logical operation with search pattern in awk?

Tags: awk

if I want to print any line containing `optimization` and `{architecture or policy or network}` using awk, how should I do it? I tried

```
awk '/optimization & (architecture | policy | network)/{print}' file.txt
```

it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `&&` operator with *two* regexps and remove spaces around `|` operator:

```
awk '/optimization/ && /architecture|policy|network/' file
```

See an [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/il67fn):

```
s="optimization and architecture 
optimization and policy 
optimization and network
optimization and awk
no words"
awk '/optimization/ && /architecture|policy|network/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
optimization and architecture 
optimization and policy 
optimization and network
```

Comment: Ah that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[@Wiktors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55759338/1745001) is correct for your example but just as an additional FYI in general you can combine regexp comparisons as (first 2 are equivalent):

1. `/re1/ && ((re2)|(re3))/`
2. `/re1/ && (/re2/ || /re3/)`
3. `(/re1/ && /re2/) || /re3/`

Note the parentheses around `re2` and `re3` in `1` since they themselves could contain `|`.

Answer (score 0):

try gnu awk by either one of

```
awk '/optimization/&&/architecture|policy|network/{print}' file.txt
awk '/optimization.*(architecture|policy|network)/{print}' file.txt
```